# How to fill the null value with product average in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have one table with missing value for unit price column. I want fill this in power query with average.
I am able to fill the null with entire column average. But I want to consider the product name column while finding the average. I want group by average to fill the null missing unit price column
Please help me to get some solution

So far I tried with below code :
= if [unit price] = null then List. Average(#"Added Custom"[unit price]) else [unit price]

But here I don't know how to consider the product name while finding the average

My sample data :
[image]

Comment: Where is your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to fill in the null with the average of the numbers already appearing there, instead of the average of the underlying numbers

addition to your code, in the most simplest form possible:

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"PutYourPriorStepNameHere", {"Product Name"}, {
    {"data", each _, type table},
    {"avg", each List.Average(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Unit Price] <> null)[Unit Price]), type number }
  }),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Unit Price"}, {"Unit Price"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded data", "Custom", each if [Unit Price]=null then [avg] else [Unit Price])
in  #"Added Custom"
```